# full documentation often not displayed in .py or .ipynb files in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I often have to go to the online documentation in the browser for documentation that in my opinion should be displayed inside of VS code and this really interferes with my workflow.  Now I noticed that my documentation hovers are "worse" compared to what I observed in a particular video (link at the end of post) and in some screenshots over the internet. Worse regarding

- the amount of information displayed
- the formatting
- the "stickyness" of the hover popup

**Example 1: print function**

The [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/VVDHU_TWwUg?list=PLqnslRFeH2UrcDBWF5mfPGpqQDSta6VK4&t=437) shows more information overall and a nicer formatting

[image: Desired hover]

vs the hover that i get:
[image: actual hover]

In addition, when the cusor is inside the function parentheses in the video, the documentation popup remains open, the parameters that are currently written are highlighted in bold face and underlined ("*values" in this example).
I only get the code suggestions and no documentation when typing the function arguments.

**Example 2: torch.optim.SGD()**

Another example is the SGD() class from pytorch, where [in the video](https://youtu.be/VVDHU_TWwUg?list=PLqnslRFeH2UrcDBWF5mfPGpqQDSta6VK4&t=216) you can see a rich popup includig the class signature, description of the class, description of the class parameters.

[image: Desired hover]

When I hover, i only get a minimalistic hover with the class signature, no descriptions at all.

[image: actual hover]

Also the suggest hover does not provide any further information:
[image: actual suggestion hover]

The video author mentions in one of his comments that he only uses the standard python extension. I went through the vs code settings and extension settings but I could not find any setting to reproduce a similarly detailed documentation output. I also installed a fresh vs code with only the python extension on a different machine, the documentation still looks the same.

The video is from 2019, so I am wondering if these in my view "worse" documentation hovers are due to some design choices and nothing can be done about it, or if there is maybe some setting I may have overlooked.

Edit: He technically does not hover with the mouse in the shown examples, instead he writes code. [Here](https://youtu.be/VVDHU_TWwUg?list=PLqnslRFeH2UrcDBWF5mfPGpqQDSta6VK4&t=338) you can see another example of him writing a function and then hovering over it, showing a colorful very rich output.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: please add a timestamp to the video link.

Answer (score 0):

This is a video without timeliness.

If you installed the package by command `pip install torch`, you'll find that there is no description of `GSD()` in `.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\optim\sgd.pyi`.

Because the package did not provide an explanation, this is not a problem with the language server.

Comment: the sgd.pyi file only contains the type hints, but the sgd.py file in the torch module contains a long docstring under 

`SGD.__doc__ = r"""\  .... """ `


How do I display this docstring in VS code? Going to the class definition is not really an option because the unformatted docstring is just not legible...

Comment: The video is a couple of years old, yes. But that is not a satisfying explanation as to why i experience a worse functionality.

Comment: are you saying that with a different installation method the documentation may be different?